# Is it possible/How to log SSL handshake information in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ssl, ssl-handshake

I need to log as much as possible information about SSL Handshake using .NET for mTLS.

This is possible in Java by using `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");`

Is there an equivalent in .NET?

Comment: Platform and Framework are relevant here. On windows everything should end up in the ETW(Event Tracing for Windows) logs. In Windows both the framework parts and the Kernel parts (Net does not do all by itself) will log there. On Linux openssl is used. You may want to look up what logging facility opensll brings with it (In the hopes it does).

Comment: I am using only Windows here, is there a way to retrieve the logs in C# .Net

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework? Both work on Windows. .NET 5 and later are .NET *Core* versions. The `Core` part was removed for marketing purposes.

Comment: Why are you asking anyway? Almost all web servers require TLS 1.2 by now. All supported Windows versions support TLS 1.2. If the handshake fails the exception, including any inner exceptions, will explain what's wrong. If client and server can't find a common algorithm the exception will mention it.

Comment: I am using .NET Framwork, the optional handshake log was requested as a functionality (The BA has java background, and this is available easily in Java)